# If Statement Condition Fails when Catching ""

Tags: vb.net

I have a string:

```
Dim email As String = "sampleuser@email.com;"
```

I try to get the e-mail address only so I split it:

```
Dim emailArray As String() = Split(email, ";", 2)
```

In the array that contains the split string, VB is seeing the email address (0) and "" (1)

When I try to add the e-mail address to a message by looping through the array using the following:

```
For count As Integer = 0 to emailArray().Length - 1
  If emailArray(count) <> "" Then
    message.To.Add(emailArray(count))
  End If
Next
```

The problem is the program still tries to add "" in the e-mail address.

Comment: the email sample does not contain a ";", so all the text is in one element.  In questions, it is clearer to use `String.Empty` than `""`.

Comment: @Plutonix Actually, the sample contains a ";" in the end.

Comment: @Plutonix I **strongly** disagree. `String.Empty` instead of `""` adds no clarity whatsoever and makes the code needlessly six times longer.

Comment: Your code works as you expect for me

Comment: @Plutonix You said the smaple doesn't contain a ";" -- it does. What worked for me though is using Not String.isNullOrWhitespace(). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the semi colon at the end....@KonradRudolph I said **in the question** to use String.Empty; dbl quotes make it hard to tell if they are trying to escape something or botched a `code tag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using String.IsNullOrEmpty instead of your comparison so it would look something like this

```
For count As Integer = 0 to emailArray().Length - 1
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailArray(count)) Then
    message.To.Add(emailArray(count))
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I've done this. I also look at what value it's getting and it's showing "a"c. I have no idea why.

Comment: Hi @bechbd, I used isNullorWhitespace instead of IsNullOrEmpty. I stil accepted your answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [*proper* `String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim results = email.split(new Char() { ";"c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

One line instead of a loop.

More generally, use .NET framework methods instead of VB legacy functions (i.e. avoid stuff like `Split(…)` and use `String.Split` instead). Also, use `For Each` loops instead of index-based loops.